# How to group data using GoogleVis in R

Tags: r, googlevis

I have this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(country=c("US", "GB", "BR", "US"),
                 val1=c(1, 3, 4, 6),
                 val2=c(23, 12, 32, 17))
```

When I plot the Bar Chart using `GoogleVis`, it gives me barlines for each country (US twice).

```
Bar1 <- gvisBarChart(df, xvar="country", yvar=c("val1", "val2"))
plot(Bar1)
```

What I actually want is to group by US as sum of `val1` and `val2` on a graph.

Answer (score 0):

Try aggregating your data first.

```
library(googleVis)
df.summary <- aggregate(cbind(val1, val2) ~ country, data=df, FUN = sum)
df.summary

##   country val1 val2
## 1      BR    4   32
## 2      GB    3   12
## 3      US    7   40

Bar1 <- gvisBarChart(df, xvar="country", yvar=c("val1", "val2"))
plot(Bar1)
```

Comment: Thanks Jason for the quick response but I actually want to know some gvisBarChart parameter which does that like in ggplot there is s group parameter

Comment: or facet_grid in ggplot

Comment: guess there isn't such a parameter (and I thing this would be not very useful). Like said by user4789639, you should "tidy" your data first and after do the plot.